# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: Error: no display specified

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, pentaho

help from anyone will be appreciated. I have implemented the selenium using java in Pentaho ETL using user defined java class. I have to automate the Browser to to download files using the pentaho ETL. This ETL is working fine at the GUI level.But when I try to schedule it using the crontab it is giving the error.I have used the selenium-java-2.45.0  , selenium-java-2.45.0-srcs.jar,  selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar.

I tried implemented the Xvfb also.I followed the below URL to install xvfb and set display variable.
http://ithubinfo.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-install-and-configure-xvfb-in.html

But still i'm getting the following error

```
GConf Error: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
```

Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

```
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    Processor.processRow(Processor.java:41)
    org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
    org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at Processor.processRow(Processor.java:41)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'enst01ap22pr', ip: '10.250.225.6', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
        Processor.processRow(Processor.java:41)
        org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
        org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at Processor.processRow(Processor.java:41)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

```
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 10 more
```

2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Error: no display specified
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Error: no display specified
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - System info: host: 'enst01ap22pr', ip: '10.250.225.6', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at Processor.processRow(Processor.java:41)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Error: no display specified
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Error: no display specified
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
2015/08/18 02:20:21 - User Defined Java Class.0 -       ... 10 more

Comment: What is your firefox version?